# remove index.php from url in codeigniter in cpanel

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, cpanel

I am not using local host. I have codeigniter installed on cpanel. 
   following are changes which i did in config.php
    before

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

after

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

also changed uri protocol

```
$config['uri_protocol'] =  'REQUEST_URI';
```

->htaccess file

```
Deny from allDirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

####################
# Forcing HTTPS #
####################
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^brittvendors.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.brittvendors.com/stitch/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./$1 [L,QSA]

####################
# GZIP COMPRESSION #
####################
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

##########################
#  expire dates for cache #
##########################
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
```

What changed I need to make to get result on
    http://brittvendors.com/stitch/home/index
instead of http://brittvendors.com/stitch/index.php/home/index

Answer (score 1):

Add following code to .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond $1
 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond
 %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```